# How to use parts of code more than once

Tags: asp.net, methods, code-behind

Im new to programming but i will first show the code and then explain what im trying to do

```
private void ModalBody()
{
    LoadTemplateOverride();
    divModalBody.InnerHtml = 
}
private void LoadTemplateOverride()
{
    string templateURL = String.Format("{0}/leadgen/eodemails/templatecontroller.aspx?eodid={1}", site.Get("InternalApiUrl"), Email.ID);
    HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(templateURL) as HttpWebRequest;

    HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

    tbSubject.Text = response.Headers["EmailSubject"];
    tbBody.Text = (new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())).ReadToEnd();
}
```

so what im trying to do is call "LoadTemplateOverride" to ModalBody, and then make `divModalBody.InnerHtml =` from ModalBody equal `(new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())).ReadToEnd();` from LoadTemplateOverride. But whenever i do, it doesnt recognize "response"...

Answer (score 2):

I'm very puzzled about what you're trying to do, but one problem is clear, and that is that you don't seem to realize that the instance of "response" in LoadTemplateOverride() you're trying to call from ModalBody() is private to the method it is found in, and is inaccessible to ModalBody().

Not only that, but once LoadTemplateOverride() has finished executing, the objects declared in it no longer exist for any practical purpose.  If you are trying to set the value of divModalBody.InnerHtml to the value of the response instance that came into existence while LoadTemplateOverride() was executing, then I would suggest that you have LoadTemplateOverride() not return void, but HttpWebsponse instead.  Then your call to LoadTemplateOverride() could be combined with setting the value of divModalBody.InnerHtml to what it returns.  For example:

```
private void ModalBody()
{
    divModalBody.InnerHtml = LoadTemplateOverride();
}
private HttpWebResponse LoadTemplateOverride()
{
    string templateURL = String.Format("{0}/leadgen/eodemails/templatecontroller.aspx?eodid={1}", site.Get("InternalApiUrl"), Email.ID);
    HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(templateURL) as HttpWebRequest;

    HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

    tbSubject.Text = response.Headers["EmailSubject"];
    tbBody.Text = (new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())).ReadToEnd();

    return response;
}
```